# align text with bottom of images

Tags: css

Starting with the markup

```
#row { }
#label { float: left; width:100px }
#image { float: left }

<div id="row">
    <div id="label">Label Here</div>
    <div id="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100"></div>
    <div id="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100"></div>
</div>
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hyx5n/

I would like to move the label down to the bottom edge of the images.  So it looks like this:

[image: mockup]

I have tried putting "position: relative" in the container and "position absolute" in the label div.  But then the images are no longer in the same row: http://jsfiddle.net/Hyx5n/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uac3Z/

Basically,

```
<div id="row">
    <div id="label">Label Heere</div>
    <div id="images">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

with

```
#row { position:relative; float:left; }
#label { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width:100px }
.image { float: left }
#images { margin-left: 110px }
```

I made a div#images that encapsulates both other div.image's. Then those div#row was set to float, having the text lying on the bottom. Hence, The div#label would appear above the image. In order to have the div#label on the left of the image, I made the div#images have a margin-left of 110px (as div#label would have 100px).

Also note that your current div#image should be a class and not an id, because you use it more than once.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like the following (http://jsfiddle.net/Hyx5n/10/). One of the many uses of `vertical-align` property. This involves removing the `<div>`'s and the `float` though. You can probably replace these with `<span>`'s with `display:inline-block` to give more flexibility.

HTML:

```
<div id="row">
    <span id="label">Label Here</span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#row { vertical-align:bottom }
#label { display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks this works and is simpler if you don't need the divs. In my real version however I do use the divs today, I have images but also text absolutely positioned over each image.  Although maybe that could be done with inline-block spans I will try it.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. By the way in bootstrap 3 img has default vertical align middle so  add style="vertical-align: baseline" to the img